Free 2D nesting software for commandline/toolchain use
I'm looking for software for nesting 2D shapes for laser cutting. I would like to use this software to combine multiple shapes into a single sheet for cutting, as part of an automated Makefile-based build process in an open source project I've released.
Ideally the software would be cross-platform, but failing that Linux would be sufficient. I would like something relatively easy to acquire and install. Something included in various distributions would be ideal. Something requiring several manual installation steps, or effectively requiring me to fork it into my own project, would be a non-starter. A cloud-based solution would be acceptable as long as it doesn't require manually registering or acquiring an API key. Basically, I would like everything to work after a user (who possibly doesn't have a lot of experience in this stuff) pulls my project's code down and executes a few simple installation commands from the readme.md, rather than forcing them (or me) to deal with Docker and such.
Top-quality nesting is not a requirement, but the results should at least be reasonable.
Currently I'm using deepnest.io to manually nest, which is great but which only works through a GUI. (There's also this wrapper, but that has significant external dependencies and does not look straightforward for users to install.) I've also looked into SVGNest from the same developer, but that likewise works through a GUI. I've found QCAD/CAM, which looks ideal functionality-wise but is not freely available. pysvgnest is nearly ideal but it only nests by bounding box so the nesting itself is quite poor.

I have this exact same problem, did you end up finding anything?

I did not, I’m afraid. Have been meaning to patch deepnest to do it but haven’t done it yet.
